# How to turn on camera flash or torch in Java ME / J2ME?

Tags: java-me, camera, midlet, light

I have created a midlet that takes photos.

Is there any way to turn on the devices flash/torch in my code? If so, is a particular API required?

(The device I'm developing for is a Sonim XP3300.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mr_lou pointed out, JSR-234 was indeed required (in particular, the FlashControl class) but it turns out this JSR is not supported by the Sonim XP3300 as a NoClassDefError is thrown when I try to reference FlashControl in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Must admit I haven't used it myself (yet), but I believe the device must support JSR-234 before you can control advanced stuff like that.
So first check if the device supports JSR-234, and then look into the documentation for possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Have been looking up JSR-234 and it does indeed have a FlashControl class. I've found a code snippet here - http://developer.samsung.com/java/technical-docs/Advanced-Mutlimedia-Supplements-JSR-234 - but do you know where the officialy API documentation is for JSR-234??

Comment: I think you can download and/or view it here: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=234